# No known package error. Android 5.0

Tags: java, android, eclipse, r.java-file, android-5.0-lollipop

I've been developing using the Android L preview. Today I've spent all day trying to set up eclipse so that I can develop using the new APIs. I've run into so many problems, and have hashed most out by just making a new workspace.

A persisting problem is the one shown below. These resources are in the R.java file and are in the resource folder. I haven't moved anything or changed anything about the project other that the target build sdk. The error is occurring any time I try to access a resource using the format R.XXX.XXXX. What could the reason be? Any ideas?

[image]

Comment: Having the same issue, just updated my SDK to the most recent 5.0 release (API 21) and this started happening on all of my projects.

Comment: See my answer, hopefully that's it?

Comment: Glad it worked! Unfortunately, no such luck on my end. Buggy SDK I guess, I am gonna try a fresh install.

Comment: I'm encountering a similar problem when adding a resource to res/raw. Did you by any chance have luck by reinstalling? If so I'll resort to that :P

Comment: Fresh install and all is good. Just got the new bundle from https://developer.android.com/sdk/index.html?hl=i - it is worth noting it comes with the api 20 compiler meaning you will likely want to upgrade your sdk from the sdk manager to api 21 first thing.

Comment: Well it took a while, but yes I think it was just a bug. Completely reset environments and now the same project is compiling and running fine.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

EDIT: NEW ANSWER
Something was just bugging out. Not sure what, but after re-downloading the bundle, downloading API 21, restarting laptop etc etc my same project is running just fine. Hopefully this isn't temporary.

Bundle: https://developer.android.com/sdk/index.html?hl=i

PREVIOUS ANSWER: Some of my resources had digits in the filename.

This doesn't seem to be documented. I found this by first trying to start from scratch, building up my app in a new project. This worked until I had to make a big jump, adding lots of activities at the same time due to dependencies, and this caused the same error to occur. I then starting bit by bit stripping down my app. Found that upon deleting those resources, the errors subsided.

I thought that a-z and 0-9 were allowed. Files with these characters worked just fine in previous Android versions, but it seems that updates made when switching to Android 5.0 makes 0-9 invalid.

Can anyone else confirm this?